# HTML/CSS layout question

Tags: html, css

I just need a little help with some CSS layout if you don't mind.

I've got three things I'm trying to play around with and I need some help making this work the way I was hoping.

I've got the `<body>` element of a page, which I'd like to be `100%` of the browser window, obviously.

Then I've got two `<div>` elements which I'd like to stack on top of each other, but the trick is this, I'd like the bottom `<div>`, (a menu which should really be a fixed height) to determine the height of the top `<div>`.

Is there a way to lay this out in CSS?

Comment: Can you give more information on why you want that?  There might be a better approach but we can't help with out a better understanding of the intention.  Code is also usually a good idea.

Comment: There are more factors to take into account. Are you basically saying that the bottom `<div>` should be sticking to the bottom of the page regardless of the total height (so that it still stays there when the top `<div>` is higher than the viewport and thus should get the scrollbar alone)? Or do you want to expand the top `<div>` to the bottom of the page if its content is smaller than the total height of the viewport? That makes quite a difference in the answers.

Comment: I agree, what is the intent? Are you trying to get rid of the scrollbars? I think focusing on only having the bottom bar be a specific height is sufficient, and leave the rest of the page alone.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want the height of the first `<div>` to have a height of `<body>` minus second `<div>`.

If you're using percentages in your layouts, then you can make one have a height of 90% and the other 10%.

But if you're using pixel sizes, you'll need to use javascript. There's no way to determine height by subtraction in CSS 2. You can use `offsetHeight` to get the pixel height of an element and `style.height` to set the height of the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the bottom `<div>` to be fixed to the bottom of the viewport all the time regardless of the height of the top `<div>`, then set its `position` to `fixed`. E.g.

```
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Else if you want to expand the top `<div>` to the bottom of the page if its content is smaller than the total height of the viewport, i.e. the "sticky footer" technique, then have a look [here](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) or [here](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).

Comment: That's a good solution, unless the top `<div>` gets too long, which would then be covered by the bottom `<div>`. But a bottom margin on the top div might fix that.